# Jest/Typescript Error on trying to access done() argument

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, jestjs, supertest

I have the following test case on a Node.JS application using Typescript and Jest:

```
/* Make sure app (and thefore its routes) are done loading before testing */

beforeAll(async () => {
  await app.ready()
})

afterAll(async () => {
  await app.close()
})

describe('User can create a new account', () => {
  it('should return a status code of 201 to indicate success', async (done) => {
    const response = await request(app.server).post('/users/create').send({
      email: 'account@jest.com',
      password: 'weakpassword123',
    })

    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201)
    done()
  })
})
```

Before this code (without using done argument on it) I was getting the following message after jest ran the test successfully:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

Then I attempted to get the done parameter to add after expect, I also tried getting it on afterAll method, but either way I get the following Error on my IDE:

`Argument of type '(this: TestContext, done: DoneFn_2) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestFn'. Type '(this: TestContext, done: DoneFn_2) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseReturningTestFn'.ts(2345)`

Comment: Try wrapping `const response` with a try/catch - it seems like it's not returning what you want. `Done()` is only used if you are using callbacks instead of promises

Comment: Try `await request(app)`